# Doctrine- Cannot update query with multiple ways

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'd like to update query. first, I have an array like this :

```
array:5 [▼
  0 => 2
  1 => 9
  2 => 10
  3 => 531
  4 => 635
]
```

named `$restaurants`. All I want is update restaurantIsSelected field with this array. Here is my codes

first way:

```
public function resetChosenRestaurants(array $restaurants) {
    dd($restaurants);
    $query = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
    $query
        ->update($this->entityClass, "Restaurants")
        ->set("Restaurants.restaurantIsSelected", NULL)
        ->where($query->expr()->in('Restaurants.restaurantId', $restaurants))
        ->getQuery()->getSQL();
    dd($query);
}
```

And here is my second way:

```
public function resetChosenRestaurants(array $restaurants) {

    $query = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
    $query
    ->update($this->entityClass, "Restaurants")
        ->set("Restaurants.restaurantIsSelected", NULL)
        ->where("Restaurants.restaurantId IN :restaurantId")
        ->setParameter("restaurantId", $restaurants)
        ->getQuery()->execute();
    dd($query);
}
```

I got an error in both situation :

```
Error: Expected Literal, got 'WHERE'
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it with param:

```
public function resetChosenRestaurants(array $restaurants) {
    $query = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
    $query
        ->update($this->entityClass, "Restaurants")
        ->set("Restaurants.restaurantIsSelected", ':null')
        ->where($query->expr()->in('Restaurants.restaurantId', $restaurants))
        ->setParameter('null',null)
        ->getQuery()->execute();
}
```